# Old Google listing uses HTTPS, new site uses HTTP, what are my options?

Tags: http, redirect, https

When googling the site, the result comes up with an HTTPS link, causing the site throw an error:

> "This site can’t be reached ... refused to connect".

If you navigate to the regular `www.site.com`, everything works.

I submitted to Google to re-crawl the site but am losing out on people that may be clicking through.

What are my options?

Comment: Use a redirect from https:// to http:// on your server

Comment: I've tried adding 
```RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}``` 
to my .htaccess file but it is still not redirecting for some reason.

Comment: Is your HTTPS port still open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"This site can’t be reached ... refused to connect".
```

This message looks like that site isn't properlly configurate to use HTTPS, if your site no have a SSL protocol installed, you need install to resolve problem. If you is using host with cPanel you can use [AutoSSL](https://blog.cpanel.com/autossl/) feature. This will be more simple solution for you.

If you no have host with cPanel, you can buy a [SSL cheap](https://customer.globessl.com/aff.php?aff=329) like standard SSL